# Can I run a specific group of gradle tasks

Tags: gradle, gradle-task

I have a set of gradle tasks which can run in any order
and I grouped them into 3 sets A, B and C

is there a way to run a specific group of task ? like I want to run only A
only B and may be a combination of A & B

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you pretty much answered it yourself, unless I am missing something :)

You group them into aggregate tasks, and this allows you to do what you want. These tasks don't need to have any actions attached.

For example, if you have a bunch of task like `foo`, `bar` and `baz`, you can group them  like this:

```
// Individual tasks
task foo { doLast { logger.quiet("foo!")} }
task bar { doLast { logger.quiet("bar!")} }
task baz { doLast { logger.quiet("baz!")} }

// Aggregate tasks (groups)
task A(dependsOn: ["foo", "bar"])
task B(dependsOn: ["foo", "baz"])
task C(dependsOn: ["baz"])
```

Running `A` executes `foo` and `bar`:

```
$ gradle A

> Task :bar
bar!

> Task :foo
foo!

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 1s
2 actionable tasks: 2 executed
```

Running both `A` and `B` executes them all:

```
$ gradle A B

> Task :bar
bar!

> Task :foo
foo!

> Task :baz
baz!

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 1s
3 actionable tasks: 3 executed
```

---

**Update:** Sorry, didn't realize you were talking about the actual `group` property on tasks.

I am pretty sure that you will still have to create a task yourself for each group, but you can simplify the dependency definition with something like this:

`A.dependsOn(tasks.matching { it.group = "A" })`

If you have many groups, you can further automate the creation of the grouping tasks like this:

```
tasks.findAll{}.each { task ->
    tasks.maybeCreate(task.group).dependsOn(task)
}
```

Comment: thats a nice thing to do, but i have 100s of tasks which have to run when I run A and when I create the new task I decide it has to be with A or B or C or something else.